# How to do this style while the variable is null?

Tags: wpf

I binded a string variable named FP to a textbox's text beaucase I want to show the FP in textbox.

And now i want to do this:

if the variable FP is null,change the textbox's background to red,and change textbox's text to "Warning!Your string is null".

How can I do it?Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `Style` with a `DataTrigger`:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding FP, TargetNullValue='Warning!Your string is null'}">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FP}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

**Edit:**

> I tried,it works~but another question is:if the FP is empty but not null,it not works.How can I solve this?

Try this then:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding FP}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FP}" Value="">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Warning! Your string is empty" />
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: I tried,it works~but another question is:if the FP is empty but not null,it not works.How can I solve this?thank you.

Comment: FP is empty means  FP="",Like this.